# Rails 3.2 Boostrap 3 Set Date_Select default value to prompt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, datepicker, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to have my date select fields default to "Select month", "Select dat", and "Select year"

I've read that you can not combine default with prompt because default doesn't recognize prompt.  I'm using Bootstrap but I don't believe that is very relevant.

This code does add "Select day", etc to the options but it is defaulting to nil since that what my user's birthdate is at the time of the form.

Is there a straightforward solution?  Seems like a common problem.

```
        <%= ff.date_select :birth_date, prompt: true, 
        :prompt => { :day => 'Select day', :month => 'Select month', :year => 'Select year' },
        include_blank: true, 
        :default => {:year=>"Select year", :month=>"Select month", :day=>"Select day"} %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the prompt twice, as one is enough. Try this and let me know.

```
<%= ff.date_select :birth_date,:prompt => { :day => 'Select day', :month => 'Select month', :year => 'Select year' }  %>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping.  That is defaulting to the current user's birthdate or for users with no birthdate it is defaulting to today's date.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? if User have not birthdate, then it will prompt user to select day, select month, select year. just remove the default from the line

Comment: But it does not default to "Select Day" ... it defaults to blank fields and "Select Day" is the first option

Comment: show me the schema of ':birth_date' please, is it date?

Comment: Yes.  Your solution worked when I removed the default hash I will mark it as correct.  On to the next problem...how to change the select field sizes :-/

Comment: what do u mean by how to change the select field sizes? please join this chat room and i will help you --=> http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51624/rails-help

Comment: Sadly, I do not have the Stackoverflow points to use the chat.  The Fields to select the date, month, and year are drop down fields.  They are too large so they are not working with my responsive design well.  I would like to change the width in particular.